# Clean and easy way with ES6+ or library lodash to search up an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Assume this (pseudo code)

```
{a} -> {b} -> {c} 

a.parent = { next: null, methods: { 
  someMethod() {} 
}}

b.parent = { next: a, methods: { 
  someOtherMethod1() {},
  someMethod2() {},
}}

c.parent = { next: b, methods: { 
  anotherMethod() {},
}}
```

Now assume the depth of this chain is variable. From `c`, I want to access `someMethod` which is a property on `methods` of `a`

So I can do something like this: (pseudo code)

```
let resNode
while (node.next) {
  if (node.parent.methods.someMethod) {
     resNode = node
     break
  } else {
     node = node.parent.next
  }
}

typeof resNode.methods.someMethod === 'Function'
```

1. Does ES6 provide any internal methods to do this?
2. Does a library like lodash have a method for this?
3. How do you properly describe this? Would you just say linked list traversal?

Note- I know I can write a helper function to encapsulate the logic here but that's not the question. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: No, write your function.

Comment: @AdrianBrand well I was hopeful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can access to object properties or methods by this way, i hope this helps.

```js
var contacts = [
 {
  "firstName": "Akira",
  "lastName": "Laine",
  "number": "0543236543",
  "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
 },
 {
  "firstName": "Harry",
  "lastName": "Potter",
  "number": "0994372684",
  "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
 },
 {
  "firstName": "Sherlock",
  "lastName": "Holmes",
  "number": "0487345643",
  "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
 },
 {
  "firstName": "Kristian",
  "lastName": "Vos",
  "number": "unknown",
  "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
 }
];

function lookUpProfile (name, prop) {
 for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  if (contacts[i].firstName === name) {
   return contacts[i][prop] || "No such property";
  }
 }
 return "No such contact";
}

var data = lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "lastName");

console.log(data);
```

Comment: This isn't my question but thanks for your time. Good luck on your journey :) TIP for you, Lookup  `Array.find`